# apoyo porfavor ya intente en margin y no me cuadra

Tags: jquery, css3

Estoy realizando una pantalla modal pero al darle click al enviar este se descuadra al abrir en otra laptop, en la mia queda bien cuadrado con la imagen de fondo, pero en otro explorador o laptop no apoyo porque??? dejo ejemplo en la imagen adjunta.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir el código? Usas un framework para el diseño?

Comment: Es necesario que pongas tu código!! Quizás también iría genial si puedes revisar como hacer una pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: el contenedor del modal es el mismo contenedor de la imagen de atras? es decir, tienes un <div> que encapsula esas dos? algunas cosillas no me quedan muy claras.

Comment: no son aparte los contenedores donde tengo el <div> es en la parte de la pantalla de atras jualian cuevas

Comment: @CruzRuizDacr agrega el código, sino es literalmente imposible encontrar el problema